# Wonky behavior from \@ifnextchar,

Tags: conditionals

When I compile the below MWE the first `\@ifnextchar,` always evaluates to false, which is clearly wrong in the last case. However, the second one (within `\punctuationcheck`) works just fine. Why would the same conditional evaluate to False and then True?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\punctuationcheck}{%
\@ifnextchar){I see a parens\relax}{%
\@ifnextchar]{I see a square bracket\relax}{%
\@ifnextchar.{I see a period\relax}{%
\@ifnextchar,{I see a comma\relax}{I didn' t see anything\ }}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.e.}\@ifnextchar,{I saw a comma\relax}{I didn't see a comma,}\punctuationcheck}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ie) test

\ie] test

\ie. test

\ie, test
\end{document}
```

What this produces when I compile it:

> i.e.I didn’t see a comma,I see a parens) test
>
> i.e.I didn’t see a comma,I see a square bracket] test
>
> i.e.I didn’t see a comma,I see a period. test
>
> i.e.I didn’t see a comma,I see a comma, test

Comment: The `\@ifnextchar` in `\ie` always sees `\punctuationcheck`; it has three arguments: (1) the character to check for; (2) the code to execute if the character is found; (3) the code to execute if the character is not found. The token immediately following the arguments is what's checked.

Comment: You need to put the `\punctuationcheck` macro as the last token in both branches of the first `\@ifnextchar`, i.e.: `\def\ie{\textit{i.e.}\@ifnextchar,{I saw a comma,\punctuationcheck}{I didn't see a comma,\punctuationcheck}}`.

Comment: @wipet Your solution worked, but since you posted it as a comment, I can't mark it as an accepted answer.  Repost it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the explanation of what was going on, but I didn't really understand it until after playing with wipet's answer for a bit.  It will help me avoid similar errors in the future, however.

Comment: IMHO, it is trivial, so comment is sufficient form of this hint. All were said: why your first attempt doesn't work (first comment by egreg) and why to correct it (second comment).

Comment: @wipet --- There's nothing wrong with a short answer; it will help to keep the unanswered lists from growing too quickly.

Comment: The OP asked the same question over at [LaTeX-cmmunity](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=85582#p85582).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `\@ifnextchar` is

```
\@ifnextchar<test-token>{<true>}{<false>}<token>
```

If `<test-token>` is the same as `<token>`, then the `<true>` code is inserted, otherwise `<false>` is inserted and the input stream will become either

```
<true><token>
```

or

```
<false><token>
```

Note that `<token>` is not removed at this stage. The correct way to use this is to have `\@ifnextchar<test-token>{<true>}{<false>}` as the trailing part of the macro code, so that `<token>` will be whatever follows the macro.

In your code, instead, `<token>` is already specified and it is `\punctuationcheck`, so TeX is right into always using the `<false>` code.

Solution:

```
\newcommand{\ie}{%
  \textit{i.e.}%
  \@ifnextchar,%
    {I saw a comma}%
    {I didn't see a comma,\punctuationcheck}%
}
```