# How do I get latex to add {} after a control word so that post-command spacing is preserve?

Tags: automation, control

I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502627/conditional-kerning-with-custom-characters/502628?noredirect=1#comment1269720_502628) yesterday and I managed to find a working albeit manual solution  to preserving spaces after commands based off [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290504/111743) answer, option 2.

Definition: `\newcommand{\fox}{quick brown fox}`

`The \fox{}, jumped over the lazy dog.`

Should evaluate to: The quick brown fox, jumped over the lazy dog.

And `The \fox{} jumped over the lazy dog.`

Should evaluate to: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

If I use the control word `\fox` a whole lot in my document, how do I get it to automatically include the `{}` so I don't have to find and replace every instance of the command I write?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Add `\xspace `after `fox` in the command definition (loading the `xspace` package).

Comment: Note [this remark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/48973), though.

Comment: Or are you asking for a way to actually change your source code? In that case just do a search and replace.

Comment: Ok, I finally got xspace working. It turns out where exactly you place the xspace command in your definition really matters.

Comment: I have used `\xspace` for _many_ years but now just use `{\fox.,  This should yield the results you desire without requiring `\xspace`.

Comment: @user1738964 obviously you have to use `\xspace` as the last thing in the definition, otherwise it does nothing useful.